# NullPointerException with counting characters

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

The Problem here I am trying to solve is how to count Chars in a phrase 
say: "How Was Your Day"

What I've gotten so far is that you would set the phrase as a string then you can loop through the string to find each individual character at each index using the `charAt()` funtion. By declaring a char variable I can set a different char at a different index each time through the loop onto a hash map, now don't blame me for bad code this is my first time using hash maps. but I get this error every time I run the program, may someone please help me out here?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Main.main(Main.java:30)

```
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase: ");
    String word = input.nextLine();
    int length = word.length();

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();



    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        char charAt = word.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(charAt);
        map.put(charAt, map.get(i) + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Main.java:30 ---> What is line 30 in your code? the reference you have at line 30 is Null, operating on null reference produces NullPointerException.

Comment: my bad everyone it's   |                                            map.put(charAt, map.get(i) + 1); = line 30   |

Comment: If you got answer, close the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `map.get(i)` returns `null` when the map doesn't have a key `i`. Trying to add a integer to `null` causes a NullPointerException due to Java's Autoboxing feature. To fix this, do this:

```
if (map.containsKey(i))
  map.put(charAt, map.get(i) + 1);
else
  map.put(charAt, 1);
```

It ensures that `map.get(i)` never returns a NullPointerException.

Comment: what about the int i declared in the loop shouldn't that indicate my "index number"

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
map.put(charAt, map.get(i) + 1);
```

needs to be replaced by the block:

```
if (map.containsKey(charAt)) {
    map.put(charAt, map.get(charAt) + 1);
} else {
    map.put(charAt, 1);
}
```

As the other answer noted, the map does not contain `i`. Thus, `map.get(i)` is null and therefore, cannot be unboxed. The reason why the if-else structure is needed is because otherwise, the NullPointerException will still be thrown on the first occurrence of each character.